# Navigation links not working after scrolling

Tags: javascript, css

I'm currently working on my new website which happens to be my first go on frontend development. I realized links on the vertical navigation stops working after scrolling to some point of the page. I have tried all I can and have search the web, still not working. Here's the link to the website - http://preciousm.co/

Comment: There's no problem in this website. When you scroll the element link that you cannot click on is the current section of the page.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, your question should contain a [**Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the featured work sections are overlapping your header. Simply turn up the z-index on the header element and it will work again.